# Connecting to IBM MQ over TLS with JMS

Tags: ssl, jms, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect over TLS to IBM MQ with JMS. I'm setting TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as SSL cipher spec on the channel in the IBM MQ console.

On the connection factory I do this:

```
cf.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256")
```

And I get:

> Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE')`

I've walked through the steps here:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/472052/how-do-i-configure-ssl-tls-between-java-client-and/

I'm unsure if this error means the handshake is failing (due to cert/keystore misconfiguration) or something else.

Comment: If you are using a non-IBM jre you need this setting  `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem Connecting a Java Client (JMS) to a IBM MQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775733/problem-connecting-a-java-client-jms-to-a-ibm-mq)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am setting that - but via application.properties file. I will try the programmatic version, just to be sure. Also, I will go over the other posting to see what I find.

Comment: What version of mq jar files are these?  The version is 4 digits.  Ex. 8.0.0.12 or 9.0.0.7.

Comment: Our version is 9.1.0.0

Comment: Can you double check the manifest.mf of `com.ibm.mq*.jar` matches what you expect?

Comment: FYI - getting back to this after being pulled onto other things - I did the programmatic setting above, and apparently what I was doing prior was not getting picked up, as I now get a new error: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2397' ('MQRC_JSSE_ERROR') - so I will work through that.

Comment: `System.setProperty('javax.net.debug', 'ssl');` usually helps in understanding the cause of those errors.

Comment: Sean did you get this working?

Comment: Yeah, I hope to get back to this. Odd you asked today as I started up with this again this morning...looking at doing this: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/472052/how-do-i-configure-ssl-tls-between-java-client-and/ and also using this to troubleshoot: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/troubleshooting-javajms-ssl-configurations#2

Comment: Okay, I did get this working, now the rather strange question I have is how to make this optional, on the client side. I put a switch into the application to make TLS something that one can turn on/off, for development uses. I did this on the channel: alter channel(DEV.APP.SVRCONN) chltype(svrconn) sslcauth(optional) sslciph(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256) so one would think it would be optional, however not setting the cipher suite on client side makes it fail with AMQ9641: Remote CipherSpec error for channel.

Comment: Add that to your question and I'll include in my answer.  That is `SSLCAUTH` which is short for SSL Client Auth.  This is whether the client must have a private key or not, it is optional.  If the client has one it must be trusted.   If `SSLPEER` is filled in this makes it act as if  it was `REQUIRED`.  You can not have a single `SVRCONN` that works with both TLS and without.  If you do not want TLS you must blank `SSLCIPH`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to use **SSL**_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 instead of TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256.

The [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031290_.htm) documents the differences between IBM and Oracle JREs.